# How to use next.js, react.js, redux in html page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asp.net, redux, next.js

I am developing the application based on Asp.Net MVC but this is not important. I used react.js and redux to search part of my html page with cdn link. I want to deploy the server side of the application with next.js. Can I use next.js as CDN?

> Note: I don't want to make an independent application, I just want a
> part of my page to use React.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Next JS is a framework as opposed to React JS, which is a library... sadly it wont work. The upside about it is, next js is preferred when you have seo specific content. I hope that helps

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).